# MySQL Connector & date type 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

Please sorry for my English
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-datetime-null.html
Apparently .NET can't take 0000-00-00 date.
Im try to use code from page in my code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++) list.Add(new List<string>());

            DateTime myTime;
            try
            {
                //Read the data and store them in the list
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (tablename == "orders")
                        {
                            if (dataReader.IsDBNull(dataReader.GetOrdinal("sell_date"))) MessageBox.Show("111");
                        }
                        list[i].Add(dataReader[i] + "");
                    }
                }
            }
             catch(Exception e)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("Ошибка: " + e.GetType().ToString() + "\nСообщение: " +e.Message.ToString());
            }
```

Same error:
Error: MySql.Data.Types.MySqlСonversionException
Message: Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime

Why MessageBox.Show("111"); don't work? Field sell_date is contain 0000-00-00

Comment: How is your table structure ? I believe you have not set your date field to accept NULL values or is not filling it with NULL, because `0000-00-00` is not a null field, MySQL does have a `NULL` option for fields and it will be tagged as NULL if you look at it using for example phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

**0000-00-00 is not a valid DateTime value**

To resolve this issue you have to configure the MySQL .NET Connector ([here you can find all parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html)).

You have two ways:

1. Add **AllowZeroDateTime=true** in the connection string. This allow you to manage 0000-00-00 value using a special object called MySqlDateTime. You can get this type of object from the MySqlDataReader
2. Add **ConvertZeroDateTime=true** in the connection string. In this way all 0000-00-00 values  will be converted to DateTime.MinValue

I prefer the second.... I hope this will be useful for you.